# eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What are the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of a Toeplitz tridagonal matrix? The general form of the matrix is $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a & c & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
b & a & c & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & a & c\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & b & a
\end{bmatrix}_{n\times n}.$$

Comment: So, what happens when you type $$\rm Toeplitz\ tridiagonal\ eigenvalue$$ into your favorite search engine? Why not try it, and then report back with the answer!

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: Sorry @Gerry Myerson. And thank you for your suggestion. Yes, I got the result.

Comment: The following  are the eigenvalues of the matrix. $\lambda_i(A)=a+2\sqrt{bc}\cos{\frac{\pi h}{n+1}}, ~ i=1,2, \ldots, n.$

Comment: Good. I take it $h$ is supposed to be $i$. Please consider posting it as an answer.